# Normalize sentence punctuation in php?

Tags: php, regex, punctuation

I have lots of input sentences I want to normalize. 
What they have in common is that they don't have spaces after commas and periods.

`Oval,delicate cupcakes.Very tasty.Enjoy.`

What is a quickest way to normalize such sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$sentence = preg_replace('/([,.])(?!\s)/', '$1 ', $sentence);
```

- `[.,]` - match either a dot or comma
- `([.,])` - match and group for backreference
- `(?!\s)` is negative lookahead which means match if not followed by a space

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
$string = preg_replace("/([,.])(?!\s|$)/", "$1 ", $string);
```

Using negative lookahead `(?!\s|$)` it is checking whether the `,` or `.` is not before a space or end of line.

If you want to get more detail explanation of the regex, just use [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).